# How to get the Coloumn Name from Model rather than Primary Key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is How we normally call the data when we define `protected $primaryKey = 'AutoID';` a primary key.

But if i want to another field rather than Primary Key, How can i do it ?

```
$AuthorData = AuthorModel::find(1);
$AuthorData = AuthorModel::find(1);// How to get AuthorID='1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a unique entry (otherwise this doesn't make a lot of sense):

```
$AuthorData = AuthorModel::where('AuthorID', 1)->first();
```